# Getting a cx ID for custom search, Google API - Python

Tags: python, google-api

How can I get a generic `cx` ID for using the custom search API in Python?
`http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/customsearch/main.py`

From what I have read I understand that this `cx` ID is for certain sites only(when creating a custom search engine it asks me for specific sites), but I want it to search on google, so I can get the first 3-5 results from a google-search.

So I want to search on GOOGLE using Custom Search API, I already got a Developer Key, I just need to find how can I get an `cx` ID for searching on google, not a personal site, or something like that.

Comment: Solved:

Go to your `Custom Search Engine` -> `Control Panel` -> `Basics` -> `Search references` -> check: `Search the entire web but emphasize included sites.`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved:
Go to your

```
Custom Search Engine -> 
  Edit Search Engine -> 
    Basics -> 
      Sites to Search -> 
        select: Search the entire web
```

but emphasize included sites.

Comment: This is no longer an option.

Comment: @Cerin This option still exists. It is a drop down.

Comment: Rumor has it the "entire web but emphasize included sites" option goes away when you go to the payed version.

Answer (score 48):

**As of 2020**

1. Go to https://cse.google.com/all
2. Select your search engine or Create one and go into that
3. You can find the CX id titled as **"Search engine ID"**
4. **Public URL** also has the cx id in the Query param as ?cx=**

**2012** **Answer outdated.**

here you can find the cx id `http://www.google.com/cse/manage/all`. look for My search engines then choose from the list

Comment: When you select your engine, there is a button `Search engine ID` right of `Details`. This is cx.

Comment: Do not find this ID at all

Comment: There's nothing listed here. You can create a new one, but it requires you to specify a single website to limit your searches to.

Comment: @Cerinthis its very old answer. link may have changed.

Comment: Now you follow the "public link" and find the id from the cx= part of the URL. Not that it includes, numbers, a colon, and the variety of characters that follow.

Answer (score 24):

As of 2017 (this may be outdated in the future), here are the steps:

1) After getting the API key (under Custom Search API) [here](https://console.developers.google.com)

2) Head to [CSE home](https://www.google.com/cse/all)

3) Click on **Add** below **Edit Search Engine**

4) You'll get a search box, type in **www.google.com** and then click on **Create** at the bottom

5) You'll get your **cx** code (called **Search Engine ID**) to use with your API key

Comment: This does not allow you to search whole web. It will only give you results from google's websites.

Comment: @DonRaHulk turn On Search the entire web. remove the given site

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023

1. Go to https://cse.google.com/all
2. Click your search engine (ie. google)
3. Copy the cx shown in the table.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

On the Custom Search wizard,it's true that you will be asked to choose some sites, but you are allowed to use wild cards,  so you can type *.edu, *.org, ... so your search can be very large!

I quote what the wizard tells me on URL's formatting (sorry , in french!):
"Formatage des URL

```
Pages individuelles : si vous indiquez www.mysite.com/mypage.html, seule la page mypage.html est incluse sur www.mysite.com.
Sites entiers : si vous indiquez www.mysite.com/*, toutes les pages de www.mysite.com sont incluses.
Parties de sites : vous pouvez utiliser des caractères génériques pour inclure uniquement certaines parties d'un site. Par exemple, www.mysite.com/*about* permet d'inclure uniquement les fichiers sur www.mysite.com contenant about dans leur nom.
Domaines entiers : vous pouvez également spécifier un domaine entier en utilisant *.mydomain.com. Si vous indiquez mydomain.com, le système le convertit automatiquement en *.mydomain.com/*. Si ce n'est pas ce que vous voulez, vous pouvez revenir en arrière dans le panneau de configuration.
```

Comment: this isn't a cure all because it doesn't work for .com: "Invalid website: *.com"